# Unique constrain for values combination in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint

is it possible to create unique constrain in Postgresql, that would take into account column values and work with some value, but not with another?

I have table, where items have "code" that must be unique, but records aren't deleted from table, just marked as deleted (special boolean field "deleted"). I could create `unique(code, deleted)` to enforce uniqueness, it works if I don't mark 2 rows as deleted with same "code". If I would try to "delete" second row, it will alert that 2 rows will have same unique values and doesn't allow.
What I would like to have, is check unique field "code" for every row, that "deleted" is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a consraint. However, in Postgres, a partial unique index would do exactly what you want:

```
create unique index myindex on mytable(code) where (deleted = false);
```

You can also phrase this as:

```
create unique index myindex on mytable(code) where (not deleted);
```